# Spark v3.0.0 - WARN DAGScheduler: broadcasting large task binary with size xx

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm new to spark. I'm coding a machine learning algorithm in Spark standalone (v3.0.0) with this configurations set:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local[*]");
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "8g");
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g");
conf.set("spark.memory.fraction", "0.6");
conf.set("spark.memory.storageFraction", "0.5");
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5");
conf.set("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "false");
conf.set("spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight", "96m");
conf.set("spark.shuffle.file.buffer", "256k");
conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", "100");
```

This is how I create the CrossValidator

```
ParamMap[] paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
            .addGrid(gbt.maxBins(), new int[]{50})
            .addGrid(gbt.maxDepth(), new int[]{2, 5, 10})
            .addGrid(gbt.maxIter(), new int[]{5, 20, 40})
            .addGrid(gbt.minInfoGain(), new double[]{0.0d, .1d, .5d})
            .build();

    CrossValidator gbcv = new CrossValidator()
            .setEstimator(gbt)
            .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
            .setEvaluator(gbevaluator)
            .setNumFolds(5)
            .setParallelism(8)
            .setSeed(session.getArguments().getTrainingRandom());
```

The problem is that when (in paramGrid) maxDepth is just {2, 5} and maxIter {5, 20} all works just fine, but when it is like in the code above it keeps logging:
`WARN DAGScheduler: broadcasting large task binary with size xx`,
with xx going from 1000 KiB to 2.9 MiB, often leading to a timeout exception
Which spark parameters should i change to avoid this?

Comment: consider increasing partitions .. so that your tasks are light weighted ..... each task will be not handling less amount of data... check this --> http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201407.mbox/%3CCAJgQjQ_87xkpACXFpoOn0iuLZ2Q00qwWTLHmZfy9BAhKqDkv0A@mail.gmail.com%3E ..

Comment: Hi @vittoema96. How did you resolve it at last?

Answer (score 3):

For timeout issue consider changing the following configuration:

spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1.

This will remove this limit of broadcast size which is 10MB.

Comment: ```By setting this value to -1, broadcasting can be disabled.```
From docs

Comment: Is it advisable to disable broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me was:

**reducing task size => reduce the data its handling**

First, check number of partitions in dataframe via `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`
After, increase partitions: `df.repartition(100)`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar `WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size 5.2 MiB` What worked for me, I increase the Machine Configuration from 2vCPU, 7.5GB RAM, to 4vCPU 15GBRAM (Some parquet file were created but job never complete, hence I increase to 8vCPU 32GB RAM (everything now work). This is on GCP Dataproc

Comment: Hi @Bluelily. I am running into the same problem here as well `WARN DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size #### MiB`. I read in the training set parquet file from Google Drive and perform the training on Vertex AI Workbench Jupyter Notebook. How do we increase Machine Configuration for Vertex AI Workbench Jupyter Notebook so it can complete training? [Notebook snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JvZwrxgORxpFQEgp_R5p5l574mqIPWo/view?usp=sharing) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check memory/CPU allocation to you? And if there's a way to increase to the next capacity. I use dataproc in the previous project, hence I was able to manually upgrade those resources. Hope this give you insight on what to do next.

Comment: Thanks @Bluelily. The training finally finished running after I changed the "Machine type" to `8 vCPUs, 30 GB RAM` on Vertex AI Workbench page though `WARN DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size #### MiB` still showing.